# Find $r$ knowing that $r=\frac{60}{\sin^{-1}\frac{60}{r}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to find the value of $r$ knowing that:
$$r=\frac{60}{\sin^{-1}\frac{60}{r}}$$

I'm not really sure how to approach finding the solution.  Can anyone help me out?  I've spent well over an hour on the problem to get to this point, and now I'm stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the original equation, and or describe how you got to this one?

Comment: @gray sadly I just left home so I can't post where I started, I'll post it in about two hours.

Answer (score 10):

$$\sin^{-1}\frac{60}{r}=\frac{60}{r}\\\sin(\frac{60}{r})=\frac{60}{r}$$

Now the above equation is equivalent with $\sin(x)=x$ where $x=\frac{60}{r}$ and the only solution to this equation is $x=0$ which is not possible since $\frac{60}{r}\not= 0$

Comment: Sure, that's *one* way to re-write the equation. Personally, I prefer $$\frac{r}{60} = \left(\;\sin^{-1}\left(\;\left(\frac{r}{60}\right)^{-1}\;\right)\;\right)^{-1}$$ :P (I suspect this may actually be the original-original form of OP's problem.)

Comment: Yeah that's a nice way to re-write the equation,but if it wasn't initially written like that than you may think that you can plug $r=0$.