# Solve for r where $\tan^{-1}\frac{60}{r} = \sin^{-1}\frac{60}{r - 10}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to find the value of r where

$$\tan^{-1}\frac{60}{r} = \sin^{-1}\frac{60}{r - 10}$$

It's taken me a few hours to get to this point (my trig skills are pretty bad), and I'm not sure where to go next.  Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

**More Info:**

I actually know the answer is $-175$, but I'm not sure how to get there.

**Answered**

Thanks @Back for the direction.  I made an issue in the original post, it should be:

$$\tan^{-1}\frac{60}{r-10} = \sin^{-1}\frac{60}{r}$$

However, I figured it out using what you showed me.  This what I came to, thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: r - 10 is hypotenuse

Comment: You should show that the $60$ is degrees. You can do that with ^\circ, which gives $60^\circ$  Is this a correction from your other post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097051/find-r-knowing-that-r-frac60-sin-1-frac60r ?  If so, please review your posts after posting and make sure they reflect your question.

Comment: The 60 actually isn't degrees.  Look at the diagram on the picture that I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{60}{r}\right) \to \tan (\alpha) = \dfrac{60}{r}$, and

$\sin (\alpha) = \dfrac{60}{r-10}\to \cos (\alpha) = \dfrac{r}{r-10}\to \left(\dfrac{60}{r-10}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{r}{r-10}\right)^2 = 1\to 60^2+r^2=(r-10)^2 \to 3,600+r^2=r^2-20r+100\to r=-175.$